# How do I change the order of screens in byobu?

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

I'd like to bind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to move my current screen left/right in the ordering of screens.

How can this be done?

These are the versions I'm using:

```
$ byobu -v
byobu version 2.68
Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06
```

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/244294/gnu-screen-how-to-re-order-windows-change-the-scroll-shortcut-and-modify-th

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can easily bind actions to *shift-left* and *shift-right*, using:

```
bindkey "^[[1;2D" prev
bindkey "^[[1;2C" next
```

Note that Byobu 5.12 uses these bindings by default for *shift-left* and *shift-right*.

And you can easily move a window from one window number to another by pressing:

```
ctrl-a :number [SOME_NUMBER]
```

However, GNU Screen does not support SOME_NUMBER to be a relative value, like +1 or -1.  Rather, it must be an absolute window number, like "8" or "2".

Byobu *also* supports **tmux** as a backend, in addition to **screen**.  Tmux does have support for this feature, and it can be accomplished by highlighting the window you want to move, and pressing `Ctrl-Shift-F3` to move it left, and `Ctrl-Shift-F4` to move it right.

Comment: Also with tmux, `ctrl-a : swap-window -t -1` to move one to the left, `+1` to move one to the right. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/552493/101005) for more info.